# How to hide a component menu in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, frontend

I developing a login page and i wouldn't like to show my menu in this page. Currently im calling the component menu in app-component. I would like to know what is the best practice to hide it.

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>         
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply did an *ngIf on my menu bar element.  The ngIf referenced a function that would check if the user was logged in or not.

```js
  getLoggedInStatus() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }
```

You can see I'm checking local storage for a token that is set on login

```html
  <div class="col hide-on-med-and-down l2 no-padding" *ngIf="getLoggedInStatus()">
```

And there is the menu element wrapper with the if statement.  Should be said that I don't know if this is best practice, but I was new when writing my app and by the time I got to login/authentication I was WAY too far down the rabbit hole to re-write things

Answer (score 0):

The best way to hide/show any element in Angular is to use the *ngIf directive. Do note that the component/element will bee hidden/shown based on a condition which you will have to provide.